# How can I get a list of errors and warnings returned by base R?

Tags: r, error-handling

I don't think there's a numbered list like in other languages, but maybe there's still a way to extract them ? Or someone compiled a (hopefully exhaustive) list already ?

Comment: You mean in general or after running a certain script?

Comment: in general, all the red stuff you can get on a naked R

Comment: You may want to take a look at `purrr::safely` although I know your question is about base R.

Comment: I want a list of errors or types of error, unrelated to a specific script

Comment: So I don't think `safely` will help